# How to prevent two people who have the same reused phone number from sharing the same auth account?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase phone authentication for my app and when user create an account, user bio data and user UID saved in a firestore document. Every time, I check this user document(`Document id = UID`) is exist or not when opening the app. if does not exist I sent him to create a new account. My question is, If there is an user named `USER1` and his `UID = UID1`. he has created an account and using the app. lets assume, if this user has removed his `SIM CARD` which is currently logged in to my app and he has  bought a new `SIM CARD` and `log in again` to my app and he must `create an new account for new SIM CARD`and he does not want to use his USER1 account. Normally network providers recycled sim cards with `same mobile number` for another person. in this case, if `another person(Lets assume USER5)` has bought this SIM CARD with the same number which is used by USER1 and he wants to use my app and when the USER5 clicks my app he can get into the USER1 account because, USER5 mobile number is same the USER1 `removed SIM mobile number`. how can avoid this case with firebase phone authentication?